# How to install app from TestFlight via itunesconnect as an internal tester in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to test application in my device as an internal tester in iTunes Connect. As per new rule to install application through itunes testflight services, I installed new TestFlight native app in my device. And i got one invite as an internal tester.

[image]

Now i got one invite to test an application through Email like this,

[image]

Now i try to install this app by pressing the button "Open in TestFlight". Now its redirect to AppStore Like This,

[image]

Now i press "Open" button, its redirect to testFlight but it doesn't display installation screen of that application. It display like 1 st image i shared in this question.

This is first time am trying to install app from new testFlight. So Please give me some ideas to install app in itunes testFlight.

Comment: You should be logged in as the internal test on the device, got to settings -> AppStore and make sure the same Apple ID is used.

Comment: @rckoenes Does that mean that the internal testers need to be added as technical members with the appleID that they use for the App Store to purchase/downlaod apps?

Comment: @rckoenes - ya i used same Apple ID.

Comment: To my knowledge the user has to be ADMIN for internal tester.

Comment: @rckoenes - Yes, i have apple developer account. one of my developer have normal apple Id. now i gave rights to him to test app and gave admin rights only. still we can't install the app through his apple id.

Comment: @rckoenes i have internal tester that is not admin and is working fine, where did you read this? I have another user having same symptoms described above.

Comment: "To be eligible to become an internal tester, a user must be part of your iTunes Connect team with the Admin, Legal, or Technical role" from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was also experiencing the same issue once But later I fixed it by following this.

1. Make sure you have *iOS 8.0 or above*
2. Make sure you have installed the *latest testflight app* and you have    *logged in* using the *correct apple id*
3. Make sure you are *not using Gmail app* to accept the iTunes Connect    testing invitation.
4. IMHO

   - *Always open* the invitation from baked in *Mail client of iOS* or
   - Accept the invitation from *webmail using safari* or
   - *Copy the link* of acceptance
     from    the mail and *paste it into safari directly*

Here is a wonderful [link](http://fastchicken.co.nz/2014/11/05/using-apples-new-testflight-beta-testing/) related to Apples new Testflight beta testing it covers from A to Z in simple words.

Feel free to comment If your problem still remains unsolved.

Comment: Step 3 is critical, yet not intuitive. Bad Apple.

Comment: @picciano - You are right ! They could have done better QA work.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer save me.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting Testers from TestFlightapp.com

Sign in to the TestFlight Dashboard at testflightapp.com.
Navigate to the "People" tab.
Select the teammates you would like to export.
Open the "Actions" menu on the right side of the teammates list.
Select "Export Contact Info" to download the exported CSV file.

Importing Testers into TestFlight Beta Testing
Sign in to iTunes Connect at itunesconnect.apple.com.
Click "My Apps".
Select the app you want to enable for beta testing.
Navigate to the "Prerelease" tab and select "External Testers".
Click the plus sign to add new external testers.
Use the "Import File" to upload the exported CSV file.

Comment: Nice answer but to the wrong question, the OP is asking about internal testers (himself in this case).

Comment: @Durul Dalkanat - i did these things when i uploaded the build. Now am struck with to download that app in my device.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. My tester was clicking the link from the Gmail app, rather than the iOS Mail app. This prevented the link to accept the invitation from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

With integration of TestFlight in iTunes, there is no need to add Device Id for internal Testing. Please follow below steps to install app.

1. Add application on iTunesconnect.com If you want to use application for Internal Testing, then there is no need to add all metadata.
2. Add username for which you using to install application from iTunes in Manage Users.
3. Now, enable Beta Testing for that particular application.
4. Add build from XCode with Proper version number and build number.
5. Add internal Tester from prerelease.
6. Now, in future whenever you add build for this particular application, you will get email from Apple for new upload and you can upload application via that email.

Let me know if you stuck at somewhere.